# How can i show only certain columns of data table in sql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, show

I created table in php and want to show only some of column names in this table. I used `SHOW` Statement, but it shows all columns. This is my code:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SHOW COLUMNS FROM habits ");

                        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                            // output data of each row
                            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                                echo '<tr>
                            <td scope="row">' .$row['Field'].'</td>  
                          </tr>';
                        }
                        }
```

How can show only some of them ? Does anybody know the solution?

By the way, SELECT Statement doesn't work for this code. It shows this:

> Notice: Undefined index: Field 
>    in:\xampp\htdocs\diagnoVisProject\HabitsPharmacotherapies.php on line 70

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the names of the columns you'd want to show you could add an array with those names. Then before you print a row you'd verify if the name of the column is in the array. If it isn't you don't print the row.

Something like this:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SHOW COLUMNS FROM habits ");
$allowedColums = ["column1", "column2", "etc."];
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        if (in_array($row['Field'], $allowedColums)) {
            echo '<tr>
                <td scope="row">' . $row['Field'] . '</td>
            </tr>';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works!!!! One more question. Is there other way for example to show all columns except 2 or 3 of it? Cause in my table there more than 20 columns, and i don't want to write all names in array.

Comment: Yea to turn the whitelist(`$allowedColumns`) into a blacklist just change the `if (in_array...` to `if(!in_array...` (notice the !). If you'd be so kind to also accept the answer, it lets other people know the question was solved

Comment: Unfortunately i don't have enough reputation, because i am not that active. But if i had, i would definitely vote for that! Thanks again.

Comment: you don't need rep to accept an answer to you own question as far as I know

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name = 'habits' AND (column_name='your column 1' OR column_name='your column 2')
```

But I'm not sure what would youdo with it if you already know the column name